# How to pass a class function to another within the same class?

Tags: c++, boost, ode, odeint

I am using boost odeint in C++ to calculate a simple system of ODEs. Both the odesys and solver are methods of the same class. I pass the odesys as an argument to the integration function but I get a `C2064` build error `"term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments"` and refers me to an error in a library header file. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

class myClass {
public:
    void odesys(state_type& x, state_type& dxdt, double t)
    {
        dxdt[0] = 10.0 * (x[1] - x[0]);
        dxdt[1] = 28.0 * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
        dxdt[2] = x[0] * x[1] - 8.0 / 3.0 * x[2];
    }
    void solver() {
        state_type x(3);
        x[0] = x[1] = x[2] = 10.0;
        const double dt = 0.01;
        integrate_const(runge_kutta4< state_type >(), &myClass::odesys, x, 0.0, 10.0, dt);
    }
};

int main() {
    myClass foo;
    foo.solver();
}
```

Comment: `myClass::odesys` takes 4 parameters, the first one being a pointer to `myClass`.

Comment: Your `odesys` function is a member function. It requires an additional parameter that is mapped to the `this` pointer. It doesn't seem, though, as if it needs to be a member function, as it doesn't refer any members, so you could simply make it `static`.

Comment: Your class did not have any member vars so there is no state inside. As this, you can make your functions static and everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the object instance (e.g. `this`):

```
    integrate_const(runge_kutta4<state_type>(),
                    std::bind(&myClass::odesys, this, _1, _2, _3), x, 0.0,
                    10.0, dt);
```

You can also use lambdas to achieve the same:

```
    integrate_const(
        runge_kutta4<state_type>(),
        [this](state_type& x, state_type& dxdt, double t) {
            return odesys(x, dxdt, t);
        },
        x, 0.0, 10.0, dt);
```

See it compiling [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97d7f2a118b0c006)

Comment: lSee it compiling [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97d7f2a118b0c006)